# Azure Backup Restore

Tags: azure, backup

I want to move an existing server 2008 instance from Rackspace/Hostway to Azure. Can I do a full OS/data backup, copy the backup file to the Azure server, and then restore from the backup file? How do you suggest me migrating this server to Azure? Hostway will not let me get a copy of the VMDK file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried contacting the support for providing you with either VMDK or a VHD file? Why are you so sure they won't give it to you?

If they don't you could do a full system backup with either Windows Backup or any imaging software. Get that backup locally. Restore the backup locally on a virtual Machine. [Run sysprep](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/) on that local VM. Get the VHD, upload it to Azure and finally create a Windows Azure VM from that VHD.

Comment: Hostway will not give me the VM file. Definitely! If I back it up and copy to the Azure VM and restore directly from the backup file would that work?

Comment: It might. But I am not an expert on how the Windows Backup works.

Answer (score 0):

You can provision a SQL VM in the azure cloud and then synch your database to it directly or copy the database files directly to it.  This has a vast performance improvement as well over the SQL Azure service and for a large business app with a lot of DB access we found that this is almost a requirement than an option.  (DB should be on your C drive so that it runs on the local disk.) SQL Azure is slow because of how data is replicated, a local VM running the service is highly advised.  We have an 11GB DB and this was the only way to get some reasonable performance out of it.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711868/azure-performance/13091125#13091125 for our benchmarks.  I've done testing on SQL on VMS and it's on par with an on premises solution.